# Azure Pipeline Xamarin Android You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-devops, google-play, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up a build pipeline for the Xamarin Android app using AzureDevops Pipeline.

The step that is causing my hair to go thin and grey is Signing and Zipaligning.

For signing, I have created a self-signed key using:

`keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore keystore.keystore -alias keyAlias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Then I have added `keystore.keystore` to azureDevOps secure files location and enabled it for all pipelines

[image]

I then set the signing step in the following way:

```
task: AndroidSigning@3
inputs:
apkFiles: '**/*.apk'
apksign: true
apksignerKeystoreFile: 'keystore.keystore'
apksignerKeystorePassword: '12345678'
apksignerKeystoreAlias: 'keyAlias'
apksignerKeyPassword: '12345678'
apksignerArguments: '--verbose'
zipalign: true
```

The pipeline runs fine without errors, produces artifacts:

Here's part of the log for the signing step:

> Starting: AndroidSigning
> ==============================================================================     > Task         : Android signing Description  : Sign and align Android
> APK files Version      : 3.181.0 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> Help         :
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/android-signing
> ==============================================================================     > /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/zipalign -v 4
>
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xxx.MobileApp/xxx.MobileApp.Android/obj/Release/android/bin/com.xxx.xxx.mobileapp.apk.unaligned
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xxx.MobileApp/xxx.MobileApp.Android/obj/Release/android/bin/com.xxx.xxx.mobileapp.apk
> Verifying alignment of
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xxx.MobileApp/xxx.MobileApp.Android/obj/Release/android/bin/com.xxx.xxx.mobileapp.apk
> (4)...
> 49 AndroidManifest.xml (OK - compressed)
> ...
> 28095862 META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro (OK - compressed)
> Verification succesful
> /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.3/apksigner sign
> --ks /Users/runner/work/_temp/keystore.keystore --ks-pass pass:12345678 --ks-key-alias keyAlias --key-pass
> pass:12345678 --verbose
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xxx.MobileApp/xxx.MobileApp.Android/obj/Release/android/bin/com.xxx.xxx.mobileapp.apk
> Signed Finishing: AndroidSigning

however when I try to upload APK to play store to "Create internal testing release"

I get the error:
`You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.`

which makes me throw my hands in the air, and shake the head.

[image]

Comment: Glad to know that you found the reason. Please mark your answer which will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT Done, forgot to do it. Thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was a lack of internal mental capacity as usual. I didn't set the output dir. After changing  `apkFiles: '**/*.apk'` to `apkFiles: '$(outputDirectory)/*.apk'` it all worked.

```
task: AndroidSigning@3
inputs:
apkFiles: '$(outputDirectory)/*.apk'
apksign: true
apksignerKeystoreFile: 'keystore.keystore'
apksignerKeystorePassword: '12345678'
apksignerKeystoreAlias: 'keyAlias'
apksignerKeyPassword: '12345678'
apksignerArguments: '--verbose'
zipalign: true
```